# When a method call's database side effects affect other clients, how do those other clients "wait"?

Tags: meteor

When a client calls a method, a `ready` message is received for subscriptions whose collection side effects have been fully synchronized. But what happens when the method causes other client's subscriptions to change?

Can I wait/yield/block the client's method call until the other clients's subscriptions have also been updated?

This would be a great DDP message and it would really help me build bigger apps with Meteor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer, I'm pretty sure, is no. Let's walk this back a bit. So your desired behavior seems to be:

1. User A calls a Meteor method.
2. The method runs on the server.
3. *All connected clients*' collections are updated due to the change.
4. Meteor verifies that all connected clients have been updated.
5. User A (and presumably all the other clients too) learn that everyone is up-to-date, and execute whatever code they were waiting to run.

Step 4 is the issue. For one thing, all clients would be held hostage to the syncing speed of the slowest client; but even if that weren't a concern, presumably some clients might no longer be connected and Meteor will send them an update which would timeout. How would Meteor know a) all the clients who are connected at any given moment, and b) whether they all received a subscription update?

You *could* work around these issues. Here's one way: you force all clients to login, and you put some client-side code that updates the `users` collection every second or 10 seconds with a field like `lastSeen` and the current timestamp. Therefore Meteor could query the `users` collection for all users `lastSeen` within 30 seconds or whenever, to get a list of all logged-in users or users who were logged in very recently. This satisfies (a). Then you could have each client run some code when they receive their `ready` message, to let the server know that they're synced; and once the server has received responses from all the clients, timing out after 30 seconds (or however far back you queried) then you've succeeded in the server confirming that all the clients have been updated. This satisfies (b). At that point, Meteor would insert a document into another collection, like `updates`, logging this news; and all clients would be subscribed to that collection, so they all learn of it. When User A finally gets *this* message, User A's app does whatever you wanted to be done when all connected clients were updated.

Sloppy and complicated? Yes. And slow. There might be ways to simplify it or speed it up, such as passing messages via `HTTP.post` and [server-side routes via Iron Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#server-side-routing), but basically you're distorting Meteor to work differently than it was intended. Meteor is designed to run more like Apache, where for the most part separate clients have no effect on each other.